# jQuery sticky footer

Tags: jquery, css, footer, sticky

James here! I've been trying for about two hours now to get a sticky footer,  but I seem keep messing up the CSS. I'm looking for a script that jQuery can handle. I understand how most of the scripts work (which is surprising, since I'm just learning), but I need the script to work no matter what the height of the footer is, because it doesn't have a dynamic height set in the CSS file of my page. Would anyone be able to supply a working script for a sticky footer? I want the footer itself to always be at the bottom of pages, BUT NOT FIXED POSITION. The content element is #posts, and the footer area is a  element with the ID of #bottom. Here is a page example: [JTB Permalink Page](http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com/post/19928717878/hello-world)

Comment: How sticky? Do you want Fixed sticky or after the document sticky?

Comment: @KyleMacey The bottom of the page sticky. :)

Comment: will the css position:fixed not work? Why do you need jQuery for this?

Comment: Have you tried something like `footer { position: fixed;bottom: 0;left: 0;right: 0; } ` in your css of course

Comment: Because there is no content that takes up the page, so the document is telling the body tag to end where the content ends, putting the footer halfway up the page instead of at the bottom.

Comment: @SpYk3HH Because there is no content that takes up the page, so the document is telling the body tag to end where the content ends, putting the footer halfway up the page instead of at the bottom.

Comment: When I got o your page, and put position: fixed in, it works fine for me, even when i turn monitor sideways (*21inches high), but i did notice, while your css mentions `bottom: 0px;` it **does *not*** mention `position: fixed;`, maybe you've overlooked something? You do have `footer#bottom` set to fixed, and maybe that's the issue since it's "inside <footer>"

Comment: @SpYk3HH OH, DUH. I forgot to add position fixed. But now for main pages (http://jamestestblog3.tumblr.com), the footer scrolls with the page. I want it to be at the bottom of every page, and stay there. That's why I wanted to use jQuery.

Comment: to use jquery you can just do something like `$("#eleID").css({ position: "fixed", bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 })`

Comment: @SpYk3HH Yes but like I said, on content pages it overlaps the text and scrolls too, and on permalink page, you can still scroll a alittle bit. This is why I wanted jQuery, to make the footer "sticky" at the bottom of the page, but not fixed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9334/discussion-between-jamescharless-and-spyk3hh)

Comment: Hate to say it then, but it sounds like you'll need to bind a custom function the [$(window).resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/) event

Comment: @SpYk3HH I know that. Once again, that is why I posted it here, hoping someone could help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok.
HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- FOOTER GOES HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 206px; /* footer height, we will fix that with jquery */
}
#footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    height: 206px; /* footer height if any */
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var footer_height=$("#footer").height();
    $("#wrapper").css({
        'padding-bottom' : footer_height
    });
});
```

I must warn you, jquery .height() function may not work properly so be careful with paddings and margins (just add margin/padding values to 'footer_height' and you should be fine).

Comment: I implemented the script, and it works. Sort of. Can you help me add the padding + margin values, because it still hides some of the footer, and now the whole page is moved down 50 pixels... o.o

Comment: Your script is not working because of ";" after 'px'. Fix that first ;)

Comment: var footer = $("#bottom").height(); /* you had #footer but your site does not have #footer */

Comment: I fixed that. Silly me! :P Shouldn't this work:     $("#posts").css('padding-bottom', footer + 50 + 'px');

Comment: It should. Be careful and mind the facebook button which is not ready on $(document).ready(). Maybe you should change it with $(window).load(), so the height will be calculated after facebook button is loaded.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9338/discussion-between-miha-erzen-and-jamescharless)

Comment: I changed it, and it didn't change anything. Can we move this to chat?

Comment: This doesn't really work for anything other than large desktop view. At smaller sizes content is hidden at bottom. :(

Comment: $(document).resize instead of on ready makes this sticky...works like a charm.

Answer (score 3):

I'll just leave this here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>jQuery Sticky footer</title>
    <!-- include jQuery -->
    <script src="jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include our scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
        // sticky footer
        (function () {
          var
            $window = $(window),
            $body   = $(document.body),
            $footer = $("#footer"),
            condition = false,
            resizing  = false,
            interval  = 500
            ;

          function positionFooter() {
            if (resizing) {
              setTimeout(function(){
                if(resizing == false) {
                  positionFooter();
                }
              }, interval);
              return true;
            }
            var
              footer_position = $footer.css('position'),
              body_height   = $body.height(),
              window_height = $window.height(),
              footer_height = $footer.outerHeight();

            if (footer_position == 'absolute') {
              condition = body_height + footer_height < window_height
            }
            else {
              condition = body_height < window_height
            }

            if (condition) {
              $footer.css('position', 'absolute').css('bottom', 0);
            }
            else {
              $footer.css('position', 'relative');
            }

            resizing = setTimeout(function () {
              resizing = false;
            }, interval);

            return true;
          }

          $window.bind("load", function () {
            positionFooter()
          });

          $window.resize(positionFooter);

        }());
      });
    </script>

    <style>
      body {
        text-align: center;
      }

      #header {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: green;
        color: white;
        height: 100px;
      }

      #footer {
        width: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
        color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header id='header'>
      Header content
    </header>
    <div id='content'>
      Content is here!
    </div>
    <footer id='footer'>
      Sticky footer content
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a great solution! Plug & play :-) Where is this script from? Do you have a Github link?

Answer (score 1):

**JQuery**

```
function getWndowSize()
{
    var windows_height=$(windows).height();
    var current_height=windows_height-100;/*change values of 100 how much u need based on your requirement*/
    $("#wrapper").css({'min-Height' : current_height});
}
```

**Code:**

```
<body onload="getWndowSize()">

<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- CONTENT GOES HERE -->
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <!-- FOOTER GOES HERE -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Just try it.because its working fine in my page.

Answer (score 0):

I just created a page that has a sticky footer...

This creates a page with a header and footer that are 55px each and the footer sticks to the very bottom of the browser window

here's what I ended up doing:

HTML:

```
<!--main header container-->
<div id="header" class="ui-frame ui-frame-header"></div>

<!--main container for app-->
<div id="content" class="ui-mainContent">
    This is a place holder for my content
</div>

<!--//main footer container-->
<div id="footer" class="ui-frame ui-frame-footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.ui-frame {
    width: 100%;
    height: 55px;
    background: #000000;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
    text-align: right;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ui-frame-header {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
}

.ui-mainContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    bottom: 55px;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-family: Segoe UI, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.ui-frame-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly there is no need for jQuery. Plain and simple...

**http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/**

Comment: God, so many people on here can't read. Like I stated in the question, the footer doesn't have a dynamic height, that's why I need jQuery. Sorry if i'm being rude, but this is I think the third time.

Comment: The footer in the example is exactly 180px height. It seems to be fixed enough.

Comment: And if 3+ people don't understand your question you should clarify your question and do some text formating. So Users will READ your question because it is easier to read.

Comment: And you should really take a deeper look at the example page ;)

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answe this question, but it was hard for me too and I was finding something in this great place, and I passed through this question and I would love to share one code helped me a lot.

You can find it in below demo.

I hope this can help someone as  I always got help from other people here.

Thank you Stackoverflow.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(window).on("scroll", function() {
  var footer_height = $( "#footer" ).outerHeight();
  var dim_height = $(".dim").outerHeight();
  var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
  var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
  if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
   // when scroll to bottom of the page
   $(".dim").removeClass("dim-fixed");
   $(".dim").addClass("dim-static").css({
   'bottom': footer_height,
   });

  }else{
   $(".dim").removeClass("dim-static");
   $(".dim").addClass("dim-fixed").css({'bottom': 0,});
  }
});

}); //Document Ready function end
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px auto;
    background: #ffffff;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444444;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.point1 {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    display: table;
    content: " ";    
    }
#footer {
    z-index: 104;
    display: block;
}

footer.page-footer {
    width: 100%;
    background: #333333;
    color: #fff;
    border-top: 2px white solid;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    }

footer.page-footer > div {
    padding: 30px 0 40px;
    min-height: 162px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
nav.footer-menu {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 75%;
    padding-right: 30px;
    display: block;
}

nav.footer-menu > ul {
    margin-top: -3px;
}
body:not([class*="static-page"]) ul, body:not([class*="static-page"]) li {
    list-style: none;
}
nav.footer-menu > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.33%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
nav.footer-menu a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color:#fefefe;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-size: 1.071em;
    padding: 0 10px 8px;
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
}

.footer-data {
    font-size: 0.929em;
    color: #a0a0a0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

/* footer extra menu container*/
.dim-static  {
 position: absolute;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background: #ddd; */
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;}
  
  .dim-fixed {
 position: fixed;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 background: #ddd; */
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<section>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>
<div>DEMO CONTENT </div>

</section>
<div class="dim"> Full width Footer menu </div>
<footer class="page-footer" id="footer">
  <div class="point1 clearfix">
    <nav class="footer-menu">
      <ul>
        <li><a class="active" title="stackoverflow.com" href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="Add a New Listing" href="#add-listing.html">Add a Listing</a></li>
        <li><a title="Search for property" href="#search.html">Search</a></li>
        <li><a rel="nofollow" title="About Us" href="#about-us.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a title="Contact us" href="#contact-us.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a title="My Favorites List" href="#my-favorites.html">Favorites</a></li>
        <li><a title="Terms of use" href="#terms-of-use.html">Terms of Use</a></li>
        <li><a title="Privacy Policy" href="#privacy-policy.html">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        <li><a title="FAQs" href="#faqs.html">FAQs</a></li><li><a title="Refund Policy" href="#refund-policy.html">Refund Policy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="footer-data">
      <div class="icons">
        <a class="rss" title="Subscribe to RSS-feed" href="#" target="_blank"></a>
        <a class="facebook" target="_blank" title="Join us on Facebook" href="#"></a>
        <a class="twitter" target="_blank" title="Join us on Twitter" href="#"></a>
      </div>

      <div>
        © 2017, powered by <a title="stackoverflow.com" href="http://stackoverflow.com/">stackoverflow.com</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
```

Also here, [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xoomserve/1znbLy50/18/)

In both demo, the Extra footer menu should stick only above the footer, with auto dynamic height, for some reason, its not shoiwng in booth demo but if you check the log, you will find what I'm talking about, and its 100% working fine in my websites.

You can do a lot with this, maybe you will add extra sub footer menu, or you will just convert your footer to be fixed/static according your document scroll status, and also you can play around and you will simply have static/fixed menu in very nice way.

I hope this will help any one else as I always got help from here.
Thank you again to everyone.

Tariq