# Default footer in bottom when no content without position:absolute

Tags: html, css

I need a layout like header content and footer.

My requirements are...

The default position of footer `Div` is at bottom even no content in content `Div`.

When the content expand of content `Div` then whole body(including header,footer) need to be expand based on the content `Div`

I don't need position:fixed for the footer `Div`....

I already tried some code in my project......

**CSS:**

```
             body
            {
                height:100%;
                margin-left: 0;
                margin-top: 0;
                padding:0;
                width:100%;
                position: relative;
                display:block;
            }
            .container
            {
                display:table;
                width:100%;
                height:100%;
            }
            .header
            {
                top:0px;
                height:75px;
                width:100%;
            }
            .content
            {
                width:100%;
                height:auto;
                position: relative;
            }
            .footer
            {
                top:5px;
                bottom:0px;
                height:45px;
                overflow:hidden;
                width:100%;
            }
```

**CODE:**

```
<div>
  <div class="header">
      Header Div
  </div>

  <div class="content">
      Content Div
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
      Footer Div(Need it,default at bottom position)
  </div>
</div>
```

Any Idea?

Note:I need to run this code in IE also......

Comment: Search google or here for `sticky footer` there's lots of solutions to this

Comment: look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9878575/jquery-sticky-footer

Answer (score 0):

add the following style to your `body` tag or `content div` element:

```
    div { 
       min-height: 500px; 
       height:auto !important; 
       height: 500px; 
   }
```

This works because IE treats "height" how "min-height" is supposed to be treated.

Comment: see my edited answer. 
don't forget to vote the answer and mark it as accepted if your problem is solved